# BeautifulSoup: scraping and iterating

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, iteration

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)  
>>> om = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'rec_title_ppnlist'})  
>>> om
[<td class="rec_title_ppnlist">  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=1">Wambold von Umstadt, Anselm Kasimir, 1583-1647 (Zeit, Lebensdaten)</a></div>  
<div><span>Theologia Germanica : Libellus Aureus Hoc Est Brevis Et Praegnans Quomodo Sit Exuendus Vetus Homo Induendusque Novus</span></div>  
<div><span>Lipsiae : Walther, 1630 [i.e. 1730]</span></div>  
<div class="rec_sep"><img alt="" src="http://gsowww.gbv.de/images/gui/empty.gif" title="" border="" height="1" width="1"></div>
```

I need to iterate this `bs4.element.ResultSet` through the `href="SHW?FRST=1` to `25000` (aprox). I have two big issues:

1. Finding `om` gives me only the first 10 records.
2. I need to build up a file with the 'information' scraped in the search (e.g. `Wambold von Umstadt, Anselm Kasimir, 1583-1647 (Zeit, Lebensdaten))`.

For some reason I've been unable to use Scrapy. I believe I could find a solution in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: you want only href link??

Comment: actually what I need is the span related to the href link, for instance  <span>Theologia Germanica : Libellus Aureus Hoc Est Brevis Et Praegnans Quomodo Sit Exuendus Vetus Homo Induendusque Novus</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
soup.find_all("td", class_="rec_title_ppnlist")
```

and see if it fixes your count problem.

For the second question use `om.get_text()` for each element in om list.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the first part what you suggest gives repeated entries. What I really need is to reach the span.

Comment: Just use soup.select("div > span")

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

html = '''
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="rec_title_ppnlist">  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=0">Wambold von Umstadt, Anselm Kasimir, 1583-1647 (Zeit, Lebensdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=1">Wambold von Umstadt, Anselm Kasimir, 1583-1647 (Zeit, Lebensdaten)</a></div>  
<div class="rec_sep"><img alt="" border="" height="1" src="http://gsowww.gbv.de/images/gui/empty.gif" title="" width="1"/></div>  
</td>,  
<td class="rec_title_ppnlist">  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=2">Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=2">Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div class="rec_sep"><img alt="" border="" height="1" src="http://gsowww.gbv.de/images/gui/empty.gif" title="" width="1"/></div>.
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=3">Wambold von Umstadt, Anselm Kasimir, 1583-1647 (Zeit, Lebensdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=4">4Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=5">5Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=6">6Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=7">7Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=8">8Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=9">9Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=10">10Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=11">11Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=12">12Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=13">13Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=25000">13Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  
<div><a class=" link_gen " href="SHW?FRST=25001">13Vomelius, Cyprianus, 1535-1587 (Zeit, Wirkungsdaten)</a></div>  

</tr>
</table>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)  
tdefs = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'rec_title_ppnlist'})

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for tdef in tdefs:
        links = tdef.find_all('a', {'class': 'link_gen'})
        for link in links:
            url = urlparse(link['href'])
            vals = url.query.split('=')
            if vals[0] == 'FRST':
                if(1 <= int(vals[1]) <= 25000):
                    print "%s %s" % (vals[1], link.get_text())
                    outfile.write(link.get_text() + '\n')
```

I'm sure the part where it reads the query string can be made nicer (urlparse.parse_qs returns a dict of list, seems strange to me).

This code doesn't check the validity of the input data (e.g. do links have href attributes) but it gives the idea about how to do the parse.

Comment: thanks, this looks nice, however for some reason it repeats the people. As I was commenting previously I would need the span related to the href link. Any suggestion?

Comment: Does it repeat the people because my test data repeats the people? I cut and paste it. There are numbers prefixing it to allow differentiation. `span` do you mean `div`?

Comment: There is no span tag in the data shown in your question. Can you edit your question to include it?

Comment: great, I edited my question as suggested and now the span is shown. Thanks